# MySQL join with sort on datetime in joined table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 large mysql tables: Articles and ArticleTopics. I want to query the DB and retrieve the last 30 articles published for a given topicID. My current query is rather slow. Any ideas on how to improve it?

#### More details:

The tables:

```
Articles (~1 million rows)
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| articleId | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| title     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| content   | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| pubDate   | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


ArticleTopics (~10 million rows)
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| articleId | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| topicId   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And my query:

```
SELECT a.articleId, a.pubDate 
FROM Articles a, ArticleTopics t 
WHERE t.articleId=a.articleId AND t.topicId=3364 
ORDER BY a.pubDate DESC LIMIT 30;
```

And the EXPLAIN of the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref    | articleId,topicId,topicId_articleId | topicId_articleId | 4       | const             | 4281 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,articleId_pubDate           | PRIMARY           | 4       | t.articleId       |    1 |                                              | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The slowness, I believe, is coming from the `ORDER BY a.pubDate DESC`. I can greatly improve performance by faking it a bit by instead doing an `ORDER BY t.articleId DESC` and having an index in `ArticleTopics` on both `articleId` & `topicId`, since in general, the articleIds are in the same order as pubDates. They are not always, however, so it's not ideal. I'd like to be able to sort it on the pubDate.

**Update:** Added EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query in various ways to see if it speeds things up:

```
SELECT a.articleId, a.pubDate 
FROM Articles a
WHERE a.articleId in (
    select articleId 
    from ArticleTopics
    where topicId = 3364 
)
ORDER BY a.pubDate DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Or:

```
SELECT a.articleId, a.pubDate 
FROM Articles a
INNER JOIN ArticleTopics t ON t.articleId = a.articleId
WHERE t.topicId = 3364 
ORDER BY a.pubDate DESC LIMIT 30;
```

The important index for both queries is on Articles, and contains articleId as first field.

If article is a large table, with say the entire PDF in binary, you can create an index that fully covers the query.  Full coverage means all selected fields are part of the index.  For this query, a fully covering index would be (articleId, pubDate).

Comment: Your first option seems to do the trick, making much better use of the indices than my original query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At this point, do you have an index on `topicId`? If so, does the index contain only the `topicId` field?

And maybe you can post the output of the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) query.

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN in the original post, which also shows the indices.

Comment: I see that `pubDate` is part of a compound index. I guess that it's not the first field in that index, so MySQL can't really use it. Am I right? If so, try to make an index just for the `pubDate` and see how it works.

Comment: There is an index just on pubDate, which isn't being used. The compound index is articleId_pubDate, shown in the EXPLAIN (I just renamed it there to make it more clear). I think the pubDate index wouldn't be used because the join is on articleId, and therefore that would be the required index for the Articles table.

Comment: Are you sure there's an index for `pubDate`? It should have appeared in the `possible_keys` column of the `EXPLAIN` result. Anyway, I can't actually say anything for sure as I don't have test data. Try and play with the indexes. Delete some of them, add them again and see the output of `EXPLAIN`.